# Storing Block of code inside variable

Tags: swift, swift3, closures, block, retain-cycle

It's pretty simple, i'm sure i'm missing something.

I'm trying to understand how to achieve the following: `action` should "hold" a block of code, that i will eventually execute inside `UIView.animate` (for example).

**What is the right way? + Should i be worried about using `self.` in terms of retain-cycle inside `action` closure?**

Sample function :

```
func forward(_ sender : UIButton) {

 var action : <Clousre of somekind?>

 switch currentPosition
  {
   case 0 : action = { self.view.background = .red }
   case 1 : action = { self.view.background = .blue }
   default : fatalError("No current Position")
  }

 UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
    action
  })
 }
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare it like this:

```
var action: () -> Void
```

There is no retain cycle.

`self` does not hold a reference to `action`.

If `action` would be a property (outside the function) there would be a retain cycle:

`self.action` <--> `action = { self... }`

Put together:

```
var action : () -> Void

switch currentPosition {
    case 0 : action = { /*do something*/ }
    case 1 : action = {  /*do something*/ }
    default : fatalError("No current Position")
}

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
    action()
})

// or

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: action)
```

(compiles fine in Playground)

Comment: But i'm declaring it outside first, because i'm assigning it only inside the Switch scope. What will his type be? aka var action : <Type>!?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Give's me error : Missing return in a closure expected to return 'Void!'

Comment: In which line ?

Comment: @Connor Neville: sorry forgot. Is no retain cycle though imo. Updated answer.

Comment: Oh... action is inside a function. I totally didn't notice that. You're right.

Comment: @ConnorNeville Much respect for pointing out. Thank you both. I'm always confused with retain-cycle lol. Have a great day gentlemens!

Comment: @shallowThought , For some reason. When i'm copying your code exactly like it is, it gives me   Variable 'action' captured by a closure before being initialized , want me to attach a screenshot?

Comment: suspect you have changed the order (`UIView.animate...` _before_  `switch...`). Whenever you put `action()` in a closer before it gets initialized in `switch` this error should show.

Answer (score 0):

Your actions take no parameters and don't return anything, so they'll be of the type:

```
var action: (() -> ())
// or, if you want action to be optional:
var action: (() -> ())?
```

**EDIT**: I originally wrote that you should use `[weak self]` to avoid retain cycles as I didn't notice `action` was declared inside a function. Since it's inside a function, `action` will deallocate once the function is done, so there is no retain cycle.

Comment: Thanks for addressing the retain cycles issue. Looks good! The only issue is, that inside the block i'm addressing ' let commonHeight : CGFloat! = 171. But when i'm addressing it inside the closure, aka :  self?.commonHeight. It gives me an error :  Value of optional type 'CGFloat?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'? . Any ideas?

Comment: The reason you do `weak self` is so that `self` is allowed to be deallocated. If self is deallocated (ie nothing is pointing to it), self is nil there. You can unwrap `self` in the block with something like `if let wSelf = self { ... }` or you can just unwrap the float with `if let height = self?.commonHeight { ... }`.

Comment: shallowThought just pointed out correctly that there isn't a retain cycle. I didn't notice `action` was inside a function.